# Postgres: Update JSON Array and remove element matched with key

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

Given the table below

```
drop table if exists documents;
create table documents(docu_id text, attachments jsonb);
insert into documents values
('001', 
'[{"province":"test province","city":"test city","barangay":"test barangay,"street":"test ST"},
 {"province":"test province 2","city":"test city 2","barangay":"test barangay 2","street":"test street 2"}]'
),

('002', 
'[{"province":"test province 2 1":"VALENZUELA CITY","test barangay 2 1":"test barangay 2 1","street":"test street 2 1"},
 {"province":"test province 2 2","city":"test city 2 2","barangay":"test barangay 2 2","street":"test strett 2 2"}]'
);
```

How can i update json array matching street key word: test ST

expected output

```
[{"province":"test province 2","city":"test city 2","barangay":"test barangay 2","street":"test street 2"}]

[{"province":"test province 2 1":"VALENZUELA CITY","test barangay 2 1":"test barangay 2 1","street":"test street 2 1"},
     {"province":"test province 2 2","city":"test city 2 2","barangay":"test barangay 2 2","street":"test strett 2 2"}]
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to remove?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name matching value of key province or any of the key and the index itself

Comment: Please add the expected ouput!

Comment: @S-Man i updated na question above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=db2d0b185af9b523c9c5863dd3507541)

```
SELECT
    docu_id,
    jsonb_agg(elements.value)                     -- 3
FROM
    documents,
    jsonb_array_elements(attachments) AS elements -- 1
WHERE elements ->> 'street' != 'test ST'          -- 2
GROUP BY docu_id                                  -- 3
```

1. Expand array elements into one row each with `jsonb_array_elements()`
2. Filter these elements by whatever you like
3. Group remaining elements again into a JSON array using aggregate function `jsonb_agg()`

---

Update:

```
UPDATE documents d
SET attachments = s.new_attachments
FROM (
    SELECT
        docu_id,
        jsonb_agg(elements.value) AS new_attachments
    FROM
        documents,
        jsonb_array_elements(attachments) AS elements
    WHERE elements.value ->> 'street' != 'test ST'
    GROUP BY docu_id
) s
WHERE d.docu_id = s.docu_id
```

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=95de3e205dd3d7a8411f5b9f1240dfa2)

Comment: how i'll be able to update the data from all the records

Comment: @Paul Added Update query

Comment: How can i handle when json having 1 item. Updating field using '[]' or null value

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Please try to create a fiddle (e.g. take mine from the answer) and model your use case.

Comment: Here is the fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=3e9c01bac4fe6e45009fbbf66acd3f1c i wanted the last part with the id 113 will have the street value of '[]'

Answer (score 0):

Updating remaining value from json matched data instead no update happened. it will update as null or empty json.

```
UPDATE street_lov SET street = sub
FROM COALESCE((SELECT jsonb_agg(elements.value) as elements FROM street_lov,
jsonb_array_elements(street::jsonb) AS elements
WHERE elements.value ->> 'street' != 'test ST' 
AND id = (SELECT id FROM street_id)
GROUP BY id ), '[]') sub where street_lov.id = (select id from street_id)
RETURNING street_lov.id,street
```